# The Gnosis questions(1)

Tags: riddle

"Twist and turn one and you'll get to know me.
I searched for years for one of the Seven,
Found him, followed him and fulfilled my destiny!
Go ask Alice, I think she'll know.."
Who am I?

This question is first in the series of a set of riddles asked during a quiz competition here at my college.

Comment: 4th line is from 'White Rabbit' by Jefferson Airplane.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XR8LFNUr3vw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Who am I?

> Neo, from "The Matrix".

Twist and turn one and you'll get to know me.

> "One" and "Neo" are anagrams.

I searched for years for one of the Seven,

> ... for Morpheus, who in the *Sandman* comics is one of the seven "Endless".

Found him, followed him and fulfilled my destiny!

> This is what happens at the start of the movie.

Go ask Alice, I think she'll know..

> In a scene near the start, he is told "Follow the white rabbit" and then meets someone with a white rabbit tattoo.

Comment: Good answer. Also, there are a lot of [similarities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_lNe4Y8yKQ) between The Answer and Alice in Wonderland ^_^