# The Gnosis questions(2)

Tags: riddle, knowledge

This is the second question in the series: [The Gnosis questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31065/the-gnosis-questions1)

"Since people look at round figures with suspicion,
They added two, to an Indian's estimation for a foreigner named object.
Look, it's slowly walking away from you..."
What is it(the object)?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But, I'll be adding a hint soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is :

> Mount Everest

Because

> In 1856, the Great Trigonometrical Survey of India established the first published height of Everest, then known as Peak XV, at 29,002 ft. It was calculated to be exactly 29,000 ft high, but was publicly declared to be 29,002 ft in order to avoid the impression that an exact height of 29,000 feet was nothing more than a rounded estimate. 
>    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest 
>  
>  I don't have an answer for "Look, it's slowly walking away from you"      - unless someone quoted this when adding the 2 feet.

Comment: This seems very likely, nice work

Comment: The 'slowly walking away' might have something to do with tectonic plate movements?

Comment: Thanks - I'd heard about the height measurement before-  - hope the rest of answer is OK or Tim's suggestion may be the one.

Comment: Well worked, kudos ^_^

Answer (score 5):

Is the Object

> PI (π) the mathematical constant

reason

Since people look at round figures with suspicion

> Its very hard to have very accurate measures for round shaped objects due to the value of PI

They added two, to an Indian's estimation for a foreigner named object

> Chinese mathematician had approximated the values up to 7 decimal places which is places more than Indian mathematician's approximation up to 5 decimal places. Also the name of PI is not aboriginal to India and China either.

Look, it's slowly walking away from you..."

> Its values has not been fixed yet and you can keep on computing it

Comment: A very good guess, i'd have accepted it as the correct one O:-)