# The Gnosis questions(3)

Tags: riddle, knowledge

This is the third question of the series:  [The Gnosis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31065/the-gnosis-questions1) [questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31116/the-gnosis-questions2)

"Link a phrase which means being depressed,
 A phrase which means propitious future,
 Something utilizing the phenomenon which results when film is exposed for a long time,
And the scientific process by which liquids(or gases) turn to solids.
"
**Who am I?**

Edit: It was not grasses, but gases. Apologies...

> Note:
>   Who am I ?

Hint:

> 1. He is or rather 'was' a famous personality in his field of work.
>   2. All these four lines fetch one(or two) word  each, and are his famous work.

Comment: Gases? Or Grasses?

Comment: No. Please try again :)

Comment: Was I trying something?

Comment: @ABcDexter He's referring to this part: "liquids(or grasses)"

Comment: Ok, my bad. Edited.

Comment: 1)Blue 2)Bright 3)Blur 4)Freeze were my initial thoughts, but I haven't tied them together.

Comment: @Solocutor only 1st one is right.

Comment: The only one that's really stumping me is the third one - some people are mentioning *the phenomenon*, but nobody has mentioned *something utilizing the phenomenon*

Comment: @question_asker Yes, this one is not easy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I've got it this time.

You are

> Pablo Picasso

a phrase which means being depressed

> feeling blue: Picasso's blue period

A phrase which means propitious future,

> looking rosy: his Rose period

Something utilizing the phenomenon which results when film is exposed for a long time,

> the only thing i can think of here is Light Painting, a technique which uses long exposure photography, and of course picasso was a painter

And the scientific process by which liquids(or gases) turn to solids.

> crystallization: his Crystal period

Comment: [Bingo!](http://lightpaintingphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/centar.jpg) And Kudos :-)

Comment: Thanks, and do have a look at the 'Bingo' hyperlink above xD

Comment: Well done! Good call on that 3rd one.

Comment: Nicely done!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you are

> Rain

a phrase which means being depressed

> Under the weather: rain is a type of weather

A phrase which means propitious future

> Pennies from heaven: something raining down

Something utilizing the phenomenon which results when film is exposed for a long time

> This one I'm a little iffy on. When film is overexposed, the picture is "washed out", and the rain can cause a washout at a game or outdoor event.

And the scientific process by which liquids(or gases) turn to solids.

> Precipitation, which rain is a form of.

Comment: Again, a good try but no. It was not what I'm looking for. `Who am I` a famous personality.

Answer (score 2):

Partial thoughts:

> being depressed - **feeling blue**
>  propitious future - ?
>  Something utilizing the phenomenon which results when film is exposed for a long time - **burn**
>  scientific process by which liquids(or gases) turn to solids - **freezing**

Comment: Only first one is right.

Comment: @ABcDexter So might propitious future be a **golden** future?

Comment: Something similar, but a different colour.

Answer (score 2):

Are you...

> Mr Freeze

I think this because...

> You said on kamenf's answer that "being depressed - feeling blue" is right. Mr Freeze is blue as seen from here: [image: picture]

Not too sure about other parts, however:

> You said my other answer to "And the scientific process by which liquids(or gases) turn to solids" was almost there. Perhaps you meant freezing? Not to mention Mr Freeze is a scientist.

Perhaps the phrase you mention is...

> "In this universe, there's only one absolute... everything freezes!" This is Mr Freeze's quote. Although there are other quotes that suit other keywords, they don't contain the freeze keyword. It's always worth giving a shot I guess.

Comment: Being a Batman fan, I must say it's a really good guess ^_^

Comment: awww dammit i just realized how wrong my guess was lol

Comment: The personality being described here is a real life one, not comes under the sci-fi.SE community...

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the complete answer but here's what I've worked out so far:

"Link a phrase which means being depressed,"

> feeling blue.

A phrase which means propitious future,

> A golden future or a bright future?

Something utilizing the phenomenon which results when film is exposed for a long time,

> expsosing a film to light uses a phenomenon which is called: Photoelectric.

And the scientific process by which liquids(or gases) turn to solids.

> well if you freez liquids or gases they become solid, so lowering the temperature. the scientific names for it are Deposition and Solidification.

At first i thought it was:

> Carl sagan, because of his statement A Pale blue dot, (but the only thing matching there is blue, you might say (for the birght future, everything falls pale by comparison) but still that would only give me 3 words (Pale blue dot) where i have 4 sentences which might even give me more than 1 word each.

Then i though:

> It might be albert einstein, when you think about photoelectric you might not directly think about him but this was a part of his work.

So no real answers yet, but maybe this helps others. I'll surely update this when I figure out more.

Comment: A fair answer, but providing another hint is that the person is not related to Science.

Answer (score 1):

I am figuring out parts of it.

"And the scientific process by which liquids(or gases) turn to solids"

> **Deposition** is the process where a gas turns directly into solid without passing through the liquid phase. **Solidification** is the process where liquid turns into a solid when the temperature is lowered below its freezing point.

Comment: You are quite close, but the exact word which should be going into connect is not yet written.