# The Gnosis questions(4)

Tags: riddle

It is the fourth question in the series: [The](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31065/the-gnosis-questions1) [Gnosis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31116/the-gnosis-questions2) [questions!!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31147/the-gnosis-questions3)

> They use me for aesthetics, because I look good and sing well,
>   They used me as signs of warning, to protect themselves from situations harmful!
>   They use me to hint when they cannot openly speak due to legality,
>   I am portrayed as helpful throughout, can you set me free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> A canary?

They use me for aesthetics, because I look good and sing well,

> Canaries make good pets because of their pretty plumage and songs

They used me as signs of warning, to protect themselves from situations harmful!

> Canaries were used in mines to warn miners of when there might be toxic gases.

They use me to hint when they cannot openly speak due to legality,

> A warrant canary is a method that some communication service providers use to tell their users that they have been served with a subpoena, even though they are not legally allowed to tell anyone.

I am portrayed as helpful throughout, can you set me free?

> Canaries are kept in cages. You can set them free!

Comment: [Bingo](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/17/c2/5c/17c25c8bd9a802b0e8589381f28a732c.jpg), good answer ^_^

Comment: Good riddle :-)

Answer (score 4):

It is:

> Siren

Because:

They use me for aesthetics, because I look good and sing well

> sirens look good and sing well, and they are used in paintings,  sculptures

They used me as signs of warning, to protect themselves from situations harmful!

> in cars, trains, ships... etc.

They use me to hint when they cannot openly speak due to legality,

> buzzers in the TV shows to replace bad language

I am portrayed as helpful throughout, can you set me free?

> probably refers Andersen's story for the siren "The Little Mermaid". So to set her free we have to take her voice as in the story.

Comment: A good guess, but not what I intended. Please try again, you are in the right direction :)